# Unknown SSL protocol error

Tags: 15.10, ssl, curl

After upgrade to 15.10 i've got error 35 'Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to ...' when i'm trying to access SSL-secure server using CURL from PHP script (PHP5-fpm). Before the upgrade all worked just fine. Any idea how to fix this?

```
apt-cache policy curl
curl:
  Installed: 7.43.0-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 7.43.0-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 7.43.0-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Accessing to https://w3s.webmoney.ru:443

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy curl`

Comment: And what is your `curl` command? Which protocols are supported by the target server? Is your key expired?

Comment: https://w3s.webmoney.ru:443 – very funny: `curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none`

Comment: I've read that there was a problem with CURL causing "Unknown SSL protocol error" . But it was fixed long ago (ver. 7.38 or so). And there was no errors while I was on Ubuntu 15.04. So it makes me think that some upgrades (CURL, openSLL etc) lead to such error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server  https://w3s.webmoney.ru:443 is not trustworthy.

```
% curl https://w3s.webmoney.ru:443
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Run

```
curl --insecure https://w3s.webmoney.ru:443
```

and it works.

---

From `man curl`

```
-k, --insecure
    (SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL
    connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted to be
    made secure by using the CA certificate  bundle  installed  by
    default. This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless
    -k, --insecure is used.
```

---

Add **trusted** certificates with

1. Add the path to the certificate to

   ```
   /etc/ca-certificates.conf
   ```

   use a path relative to `/usr/share/ca-certificates`
2. Run `sudo update-ca-certificates`

For further instructions read [`man update-ca-certificates`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html)

---

Taken from the comments:

> FYI: The same site has SSLv3 and SSLv2 enabled - it's BAD and not trustworthy at all because of that

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but here is the thing: at another server, with older software, my PHP script works as is, without any modifications. After going 15.10 this problem appeared. So I'm wondering what's changed?

Comment: The list of trusted certificates has changed. `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! After finding the list of certificates I was able to add missing ones. I understand that target site is not trustworthy and uses obstolete SSL, but there is no way to fix it, so...

Comment: FYI: The same site has SSLv3 and SSLv2 enabled - it's BAD and not trustworthy at all because of that

Comment: You're right, both should be removed in the webserver configuration.